# SQL regular expression to match blank values

Tags: sql, regex, pattern-matching

I want to query a table based on the value of a variable. If the variable is null, then I want to return all the rows.I tried using the following query:-

```
select * from abc_tbl where fld1 like nvl(fld1,'%')
```

In this table, there are certain rows that have blank values.Those rows are not returned when I used the above query. I tried using regular expressions also-

```
select * from abc_tbl where regexp_like (fld1,'(.)*')
```

But none of this is meeting the requirement. Kindly suggest a solution

Answer (score 3):

try this query

```
select * from abc_tbl where fld1 is null
```

Comment: Hi, my requirement is actually to return queries that have blank values.It's not null value. I tried this query also.But no rows were returned.

Comment: If you want blank records then use fld1=''

Comment: I tried that also.But even that is not serving the purpose

Comment: You are given example data and what you want result to specify in question